# Value of variable won't update outside loop in batch script

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I realize this question has been asked here before, but for some unknown reason I cannot get the following to work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
    for /f %%a in (whitelist.txt) do (
        if "%%i"=="%%a" (
            set kill=1
        )
    )
    if "!kill!"=="1"
    (
        echo "!kill!"
        pause
    )
    set kill=
)
endlocal
```

I have a headache over this, as I don't see how it can't possibly be not working.  Please and thanks for any help.

I keep fixing one issue, and another pops up.

I'm just trying to make a batch script that calls a whitelist.txt and deletes all processes except for the ones found.
Honestly normally I can figure this stuff out myself, but I am absolutely stumped.  Can anyone help complete this code's logic?

Comment: No need for delayed expansion here if you are using `if defined kill` instead of `if "!kill!"=="1"`...

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis must go on the same line as the `IF`

```
    if "!kill!"=="1" (
       .....
    )
```

Comment: Well, a rookie mistake I made.  Thanks.  I guess sometimes when you look too hard for the answer, it's unseen.

Comment: While you're at it, with your setting of `kill`, try either `set /A kill=1` or `set "kill=1"`; equally `set "kill="` to er, kill it. This protects against trailing spaces on the line, which are included in the value assigned on a string-assign. Perhaps also you may consider `if defined kill` - which would obviate the `enabledelayedexpansion` - it works on the run-time state of the environment.